# transfering sql server license from one host to another

Tags: sql-server, licensing

Greetings, I have an SQL server standard license, and it is being used on a dedicated server from one of the large hosting providers. If I want to move my dedciated server to another company, how does one go about transferring the license to another box? Is there any limits to how many times I can do this? (I only need one active at a time).

Answer (score 1):

Did you purchase the software or is it supplied by the hosting company? If it's the latter you will probably have to either purchase the software for yourself or see if the new hosting company offers SQL Server.

If you're the one that originally purchased the software I would talk to a vendor. Microsoft licensing can be very complicated and I would personally not want to be involved in any sort of license transfer situation without someone who knows what they are doing.

Comment: +1 - license transfers for SQL are totally do-able, but you need to be sure that it's your license to be transferring in the first place.

Comment: Its a license purchased by me. Not from the hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

It is your license. It can be active anywhere, so moving to a different hosting provider is not a problem at all. You can do it as many times as you want to.